# How Can I Add a Drop Downmenu, Selection, add that text in a richtextfield

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How Can I Make It So That:
When I Select An Option From A Option From a Drop Down Menu, It adds a text into a richtextbox for example:

```
            Drop Down Menu/ComboBox >            |Are Goood|

            richtextbox:
                        ___________________________________________________
                        | (output after selecting option from dropdownmenu |
                        |                                                  |
                        |    "Waffles Are Goood"                           |
                        | (Adds Entire Text, "Waffles Are Good")           |
                        ___________________________________________________
```

Comment: What language are you writing in? Do you have some sample code that shows what you've tried and how it failed to do what you wanted?

Comment: I Dont Have Any Examples, Im Coding In C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ComboBox(Drop Down Menu).
Then try to add this code on the event function.

```
C#
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = main_text + " " + comboBox1.Text;
}

VB
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    RichTextBox1.Text = main_text + " " + ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

you need to create a string variable store the text from the richTextbox

```
string main_text; -- C#
Dim main_text As String -- VB
```

add KeyPress Event on the richtextbox

```
C#
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    main_text = richTextBox1.Text;
}

VB
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
        main_text = RichTextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Im Kind Of New With C# Can You Explain, Where I Should Put The Code, or Write Out The Entire Fuction With Code

Comment: You can just double click the Combobox and a function will be automatically created then you can put the code there.

Comment: I DId, It Said Error ";" Expected

Comment: add ";" at the end of the code a provided, i thought your using VB thats why i dont add ";" but C# code need ";".

Comment: Still Getting Some Errors:

Code:
         private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e Richtextbox.text += ComboBox.text)
        {
            Richtextbox.text += ComboBox.text;
        }

Comment: Code Works Thank You But How Can I Make IT So It Adds An Entire Text?

Like When I Select The Option "Are Good"

I Want This to Be Put Inside The RichText Box "Waffles Are Good"

Comment: And When I Use Another, Combo Box I Would Like For It To Place A Text Undetneath The Previous Selection, For Example First Text: 'Waffles "Are Good"' <- From ComboBox1, Selection Second Text: 'The Waffles "Are Amazing"' <- From ComboBox2

Comment: In that case you need to store the "Waffles" in a string variable then every time you select another item on the combobox you just need to concatenate the variable and the combobox text.

Comment: i switched to vb, sorry, i did this before i saw latest response, and i dont have files for other, may you please, switch to vb. Thank You